# How to I calculate the load on a webbing triple slide buckle?

Tags: statics

I'm trying to figure out if this is a suitable way to create connection loops for a trampoline web.

The first pic is a fairly standard black nylon slide.  The rough middle bar increases friction.

In normal use the webbing passes through the slide twice.

When there is tension on the web, the force is going to try to fold the slide.  First order thinking is that this is going to proportional to the sine of the angle the web bends through as it goes around the end bars.  So if I imagine  the yellow web under tension, it looks like somewhere between 30 and 45 degrees.  If it was 30, then the force trying to pop that middle bar out is half the tension applied to the web.

I'm planning on using what in the trade is called pull tape.  This is flat polyester woven web.  1/2 tape has a break strength.

[image: webbing triple slide]
[image: Threaded slide]

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer.

A slide buckle is the wrong solution.  The packing industry has wire fasteners for this.

[image]

A quick video of how this works in practice:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=o5X3qOg35d0